# What exactly is n_iter hyperparameter in randomizedSearch?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to wrap my head around the `n_iter` parameter when using [randomizedSearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) for tuning hyperparameters of xgbRegressor model.

Specifically, how does it work with the `cv` parameter?

Here's the code:

```
# parameter distributions

params = {
          "colsample_bytree": uniform(0.7, 0.3), # fraction of cols to sample
          "gamma": uniform(0, 0.5), # min loss reduction required for next split
          "learning_rate": uniform(0.03, 0.3), # default 0.1 
          "max_depth": randint(2, 6), # default 6, controls model complexity and overfitting
          "n_estimators": randint(100, 150), # default 100
          "subsample": uniform(0.6, 0.4) # % of rows to use in training sample
}

rsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=params, random_state=42, n_iter=200, cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=1, return_train_score=True)

# Fit model
rsearch.fit(X_train, y_train)

Fitting 3 folds for each of 200 candidates, totalling 600 fits
```

The documentation says it is the number of parameter settings. And the output log refers of `n_iter` as candidates. What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply determines how many runs in total your randomized search will try.

Remember, this is not grid search; in `parameters`, you give what distributions your parameters will be sampled from. But you need one more setting to tell the function how many runs it will try in total, before concluding the search; and this setting is `n_iter` - that's why, at the end (results), the function reports that `n_iter` candidate solutions (i.e. specific parameter settings) were tried.

There is not any direct relation between `n_iter` and the `cv` parameter; the latter determines how exactly the performance of each iteration (candidate solution) will be determined.

Comment: I see. So `n_iter`  = 200, means the model will be fit 200 times for different combination of parameter distributions specified * value specified of `cv` parameter

Comment: @kms exactly (I removed xgboost from the tags and title as the question has nothing specifically to do with it).

Comment: So, it may or may not be an exhaustive search of different combinations of the parameter distributions, since we're specifying a hard limit? GridSearch on the other hand is exhaustive?

Comment: It almost never will be an exhaustive search; if we want that, we go for a grid search.

Comment: I suppose the relationship with cv (# of folds) is that it will run on each fold `n_iter` # of times.

Comment: @kms thought we had already clarified that in the first 2 comments here